# How to add buttons dynamically to my form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, dynamic

I want to create 10 buttons on my form when I click on button1. No error with this code below but it doesnt work either.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Capacity; i++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to assign a height and width, or they won't be visible

Comment: and once again you got a valid answer, yet you haven't accepted it or explained why it isn't suitable...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't work because the list is empty. Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You aren't creating any buttons, you just have an empty list.

You can forget the list and just create the buttons in the loop.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
     int top = 50;
     int left = 100;

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)     
     {         
          Button button = new Button();   
          button.Left = left;
          button.Top = top;
          this.Controls.Add(button);      
          top += button.Height + 2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
Point newLoc = new Point(5,5); // Set whatever you want for initial location
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Size = new Size(10, 50);
    b.Location = newLoc;
    newLoc.Offset(0, b.Height + 5);
    Controls.Add(b);
}
```

If you want them to layout in any sort of reasonable fashion it would be better to add them to one of the layout panels (i.e. [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) or to align them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems- List is empty. You need to add some buttons to the list first. Second problem: You can't add buttons to "this". "This" is not referencing what you think, I think. Change this to reference a Panel for instance.

```
//Assume you have on your .aspx page:
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_Controls" runat="server"></asp:Panel>


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();


        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Capacity; i++)
        {
            Panel_Controls.Controls.Add(buttons[i]);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case, `this` is a reference to his `Form`

Answer (score 1):

use button array like this.it will create 3 dynamic buttons bcoz h variable has value of 3

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int h =3;


Button[] buttonArray = new Button[8];

for (int i = 0; i <= h-1; i++)
{
   buttonArray[i] = new Button();
   buttonArray[i].Size = new Size(20, 43);
   buttonArray[i].Name= ""+i+"";
   buttonArray[i].Click += button_Click;//function
   buttonArray[i].Location = new Point(40, 20 + (i * 20));
    panel1.Controls.Add(buttonArray[i]);

}  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same doubt and came up with the following contribution:

```
 int height = this.Size.Height;
 int width = this.Size.Width;

 int widthOffset = 10;
 int heightOffset = 10;

 int btnWidth = 100;  // Button Widht
 int btnHeight = 40;  // Button Height

 for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
 {
     if ((widthOffset + btnWidth) >= width)
     {                    
         widthOffset = 10;
         heightOffset = heightOffset + btnHeight

         var button = new Button();
         button.Size = new Size(btnWidth, btnHeight);
         button.Name = "" + i + "";
         button.Text = "" + i + "";
         //button.Click += button_Click; // Button Click Event
         button.Location = new Point(widthOffset, heightOffset);

         Controls.Add(button);

         widthOffset = widthOffset + (btnWidth);
     }

     else
     {                        
         var button = new Button();
         button.Size = new Size(btnWidth, btnHeight);
         button.Name = "" + i + "";
         button.Text = "" + i + "";
         //button.Click += button_Click; // Button Click Event
         button.Location = new Point(widthOffset, heightOffset);

         Controls.Add(button);

         widthOffset = widthOffset + (btnWidth);
      }
  }
```

**Expected Behaviour:**
This will generate the buttons dinamically and using the current window size, "break a line" when the button exceeds the right margin of your window.

Comment: whats larguraBotao and alturaBotao mean

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a Button to an empty list without creating a new instance of that Button. 
You are missing the

```
Button newButton = new Button();
```

in your code plus get rid of the `.Capacity`

Answer (score 0):

First, you aren't actually creating 10 buttons. Second, you need to set the location of each button, or they will appear on top of each other. This will do the trick:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      var button = new Button();
      button.Location = new Point(button.Width * i + 4, 0);
      Controls.Add(button);
  }
```