# Button Array using String and Integer C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to make button array that include `string` and `integer`. I have `30 buttons` and named `B1, B2, ...., B30` and I want to change their color depend on the counter value. How can I do that? These are what I have done and I stuck

```
for(Cnt = 0; cnt < 30; cnt++)
{
   Button[] Tombol = new Button[]{"B"+(cnt+1)};  
   Tombol[cnt].BackColor = Color.Red
}
```

Comment: The button array is initialized within the for loop and therefore only exists there. Create the array before the loop and only create single buttons.
But are you adding those buttons to a form at some point?

Comment: Yes. I add those buttons to a form at the same point. I still confused with only create single buttons. Can you explain it to me ? @Franky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Control` (custom) initialization in the `Form` (in your case, the `Control` being a `Button`) requires **more** than a simple declaration. Apart from giving name (which you do), two other important things to do are:

1. To add it to the `Control` parent
2. To locate it nicely

Thus, adding those considerations to the `Button` you are to create, you could do something like this

```
int noOfBtns = 30;
Button[] Tombols = new Button[30]; //actually, you may not need this at all
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < numOfBtns; cnt++)
{
    Button tombol = new Button();
    tombol.BackColor = Color.Red;
    tombol.Location = new Point(5, cnt * 25); //Read (2) please formulate this more properly in your case
    tombol.Name = "B" + (cnt + 1).ToString(); 
    // others like size (maybe important depending on your need), color, etc
    this.Controls.Add(tombol); //Read (1) this refers to the `Form` if the parent control you want to put your button to is `Form`. But change the `this` as you see fit
    Tombols[cnt] = tombol; //again, actually you may not need this at all
}
```

Take care of how you **formulate** the location of your button, **very important**. The example I gave above is really simple formulation, which might not fit if your number of buttons grow large. But that gives you the basic idea on how **important** it is to set the **location** of the `Button` right.

You may need the array of `Button` at all, unless for some reason you want to list it. But even you want to list it, you should use `List` and `List.Add` instead of `Array`.

Comment: A typo: `New Point` instead of `new Point`; you, probably, want assign `Size` as well: `tombol.Size = new Size(50, 20);`; safier is not to use magic numbers and constants `noOfBtns` in the *for loop*: `Button[] Tombols = new Button[noOfBtns];` then `for(int cnt = 0; cnt < Tombols.Length; ++cnt)`

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work :( That's button's color still white and doesn't change to red.

Button tombol = new Button();
tombol.Location = new Point(999, 415);
tombol.Size = new Size(25, 40);
tombol.Name = "B11".ToString();
tombol.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.Controls.Add(tombol);

Comment: Yes. I update that code. First I want to try change button's color on the specific coordinate. The button's coordinate is 999, 415 and its name is B11. It doesn't work.. Can you please help me ? :(

Comment: I want to change Back Color. I have made a button on the coordinate of (999, 415) and its size is (25, 40). Its name is B11. I want to try change its color first and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq* to *generate* the array:

```
Button[] Tombol = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 30)
  .Select(i => new Button() {
    Text = String.Format("B{0}", i + 1),
    BackColor = Color.Red, 
    //TODO: compute desired color as function of "i" like
    // BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i * 8, 255 - i * 8, 128),
    //TODO: assign Parent, Location, Size etc. like this:
    // Parent = this,
    // Location = new Point(10 + 40 * i, 10),
    // Size = new Size(35, 20),
  })
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean like this:

```
Button[] Tombol = new Button[30];
for(cnt = 0; cnt < 30; cnt++)
{
    Tombol[cnt] = new Button
        {
            Text = "B" + (cnt+1),
            BackColor = Color.Red
        };
}
```

First you create the array and in the for loop you instantiate the actual buttons one by one.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are recreating your array on each loop of your code rather than creating the array outside of the loop and then adding buttons to it in the loop.

In addition all your buttons are being created in the same position, so they are on top of each other meaning you can only see one of them.

Try something like this, [based on a modified version of the code from this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608311/how-to-add-buttons-dynamically-to-my-form) which creates the buttons, adds them to a list you can search and the sets the positions of the buttons too:

```
        int top = 50;
        int left = 100;

        var buttons = new Dictionary<string, Button>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            buttons.Add("B"+i, button);
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            top += button.Height + 2;
            button.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

You can then refer to an individual button later with the code:

```
buttons["B3"].BackColor= Color.Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the button array first

```
int numOfBtns = 30;
Button[] Tombol = new Button[numOfBtns];
```

and after you can fill required items

```
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < numOfBtns; cnt++)
{
    // Name, Content, Foreground .. whatever
    Tombol[cnt].Name = "B" + (cnt + 1);
}
```