# How to assign different task to the buttons created in a loop in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am creating 3 buttons inside a for each loop and adding to a panel, how to assign different task to each button. Once assigning task , it work only for the last created button, on pressing any button, only the last button's task gets executed.

Here is what i am doing :-

```
private void LoadOptionalFactorComponents()
    {
        int factorCount = 0;
        foreach (var enrollFactor in this.stateController.EnrollFactors.Values)
        {
            Panel factorPanel = this.CreateFactorPanel(325, 120);
            factorPanel.Location = new Point(this.enrollmentComponentsPanel.Location.X, 5);
            this.enrollmentComponentsPanel.Controls.Add(factorPanel);
            Label headerLabel = this.CreateHeaderLabel(enrollFactor.FactorDisplayName);
            factorPanel.Controls.Add(headerLabel);
            headerLabel.Location = new Point(factorPanel.Location.X + 85, 0);
            Label descriptionLabel = this.CreateDescriptionLabel(enrollFactor.GetFactorDescriptionText());
            factorPanel.Controls.Add(descriptionLabel);
            descriptionLabel.Location = new Point(headerLabel.Location.X, headerLabel.Location.Y + 25);
            PictureBox factorPictureBox = this.CreateFactorImage(enrollFactor.GetImage());
            factorPanel.Controls.Add(factorPictureBox);
            factorPictureBox.Location = new Point(factorPanel.Location.X + 5, 0);
            this.setupButton = this.CreateSetupButton();
            this.setupButton.Name = this.setupButton.Name + factorCount;
            factorPanel.Controls.Add(this.setupButton);
            this.setupButton.Location = new Point(factorPictureBox.Location.X + 90, 74);
            this.setupButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SetupButton_Click);
        }
    }
```

also on click of this setup button , i am performing this event-

```
private void SetupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.renderFormUI.LoadEnrollUserControlAccordingToFactor();
        this.formUtils.GetBackToFactorListLinkLabel();
    }
```

i need help in differentiating the buttons and their events.

Comment: If you want to implement different events on the bases of "Text" than you can caste sender to button and than use if else statement to implement different logic.

Comment: If you want to do this you should create an instance of the button and assign a handler like what you did .these links can help you .https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/creating-a-button-at-run-time-in-C-Sharp/      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608311/how-to-add-buttons-dynamically-to-my-form

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your are overwriting a local field (this.setupButton). That's why you only get the last button event.

```
this.setupButton = this.CreateSetupButton();
this.setupButton.Name = this.setupButton.Name + factorCount;
factorPanel.Controls.Add(this.setupButton);
this.setupButton.Location = new Point(factorPictureBox.Location.X + 90, 74);
this.setupButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SetupButton_Click);
```

What if you don't use a local field:

```
 
var setupButton = this.CreateSetupButton();
setupButton.Name = setupButton.Name + factorCount;
setupButton.Location = new Point(factorPictureBox.Location.X + 90, 74);
setupButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SetupButton_Click);
factorPanel.Controls.Add(setupButton);
```

Comment: I tried removing the local field and creating new button inside the loop itself, the way you have told, but its still the same..

Comment: I've tried the code in a sample project where it worked. Check the sender object of the event. You should see that the sender is different. What does CreateSetupButton() do? Here is my sample code...

Comment: `private void LoadOptionalFactorComponents()
        {
            for(int i = 1; i<4;i++)
            {

                var setupButton = new Button();
                setupButton.Name = i.ToString();
                setupButton.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 90 * i, 74);
                setupButton.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

                this.panel1.Controls.Add(setupButton);
            }
        }`

Comment: Can you please explain in a better way? @eistzitrone

Comment: And also how are you passing button1_Click in EventHandler when it doesn't exist, please  explain

Comment: First of all I would suggest you to validate if your buttons work independently. Set a breakpoint somewhere within your SetupButton_Click method and see if the parameter `object sender` is actually the button you've clicked. I did that by validating the `Name` property.

Comment: okay thank you, and also can you post the codes properly of the event as well.

Comment: My onclick function was actually empty so there is nothing to show. But now I would suggest you to use the sender object to differentiate the function calls within your `SetupButton_Click` function. Maybe by adding a parameter to the `LoadEnrollUserControlAccordingToFactor` or something like that. Hope that'll help!